# Azure ML Compute Instance: How can I safely upgrade the default Azure Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to the latest LTS?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to upgrade the default Ubuntu version that comes with the Compute Instance in Azure ML.

Anyone has any guide on safely upgrading to the latest LTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any specific reason you want to do this?

Since there are some heavy dependencies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-compute-instance#contents), my guess is you have to try it yourself.

Create a new one and run:

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Let us know what happened.

BTW: Are Compute Instance also Docker images? If so, the upgrade might be working, if not, there might be many drivers that need to be upgraded too. The ones from the GPU would be the easiest...

Comment: I've actually upgraded to 18.04 LTS, and so far it works ok. But in general, I think having more options with regards to OS version is very useful. The VM machines under VM service also has option for 18.04 LTS, so I'm not quite sure why the Azure ML compute instance couldn't provide more options when we we create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for trying and reporting!

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer for now, I guess there's no other way around based on the available documentation anyways.

Comment: @AfiqJohari have you used the same commands like in answer for upgrading it to 18.04 LTS?